# java applet AccessControlException in 3rd party library

Tags: java, applet

I'm using a 3rd party library (jar) in my java applet and I'm getting this error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at sfs2x.client.core.sockets.TCPSocketLayer.initNetty(TCPSocketLayer.java:63)
    at sfs2x.client.core.sockets.TCPSocketLayer.<init>(TCPSocketLayer.java:59)
    at sfs2x.client.bitswarm.BitSwarmClient.init(BitSwarmClient.java:90)
    at sfs2x.client.SmartFox.initialize(SmartFox.java:148)
    at sfs2x.client.SmartFox.<init>(SmartFox.java:127)
    at bfwd.RedemptionOnline.Client.RedemptionOnlineApplet.init(RedemptionOnlineApplet.java:29)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm testing this on my development server and trying to connect to localhost. Why would I be getting this error now, and how would I prevent it in the future?

Ok, I even self-signed my jar, yet it STILL comes up with this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
at sfs2x.client.core.sockets.TCPSocketLayer.initNetty(TCPSocketLayer.java:63)
```

[SFS2X](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/2X/) seems to be a game server. [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) is a TCP/IP server. Why are you trying to run a game server on the client side? I'm not sure if your webpage visitors are ever going to be happy with this. What's the functional requirement after all? Did you consider letting your webserver do the job?

Regardless, you need to [sign](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html) the applet in order to get it to work. Unsigned applets have very restrictive security rules (otherwise it would be very easy to leech the entire "My Documents" down and send it to the server, for example). Basically, you need to send your code to some RSA signing company and have them to review the code and get some RSA certificate back which you provide along your applet so that clients know that it's trusted software.

You can also sign your applet with a homemade certificate which is valid for only 6 months. But the enduser would still get a security warning when your applet is to be loaded; the enduser is asked for confirmation if this is really trusted software and may be executed. You however still need to wrap the applet main `init()` inside an [`AccessController#doPrivileged()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html).

```
public void init() {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        @Override public Void run() {
            // Put your original init() here.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using a webserver. This is the client API, which uses sockets to connect to it. I'm trying to create a "translator" if you will between javascript <-> java <-> smartfoxserver. I want to utilize my HTML5, CSS3, and javascript skills to design a good UI. the java applet will handle connecting to the game server and providing the UI with data to display. I'll try the doPriviliged cause I can't afford to pay a company to get it signed. especially since i'm just trying to develop the thing first

Comment: ok, that doesn't work cause it won't let me reference my variables in my original class.

Comment: Why not? Just construct your UI main class and run it. E.g. `new UI().run()` or something. The variables should obviously be in that `UI` class.

Comment: I don't have a UI class. Just the main applet class that holds the smarfoxClient variable and evenListener instances.

Comment: Either refactor it out or construct the applet class itself and delegate. Note that the classname "UI" is just a fictive example. So basically, you can end up in 2 classes, one which extends `Applet` and is executed by browser and other which does all the desired job. That other one is than to be constructed/executed inside the applet's privileged `init()`. Or, just reconstruct the applet itself without calling its `init()`.

Comment: Well, that may be an option if you can tell me how I would call code from the non-applet class inside the browser through javascript.

Comment: Also, I tried putting this code inside the init(), but I still got the error from WITHIN the doPrivilged fucntion:

this.sfsClient = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<SmartFox> () {
            @Override public SmartFox run() {
                SmartFox sfsClient = new SmartFox(true);
                return sfsClient;
            }
        });